# "Invalid object name" Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've just started learning ASP.NET MVC. I've got a problem with Entity Framework.

```
namespace MVCDemo.Models
{
   [Table("tabelka")]
   public class Employee
   {
      public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string City { get; set; }
   }
}

public class ligiConnection : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employes { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    ligiConnection ligiConnection = new ligiConnection();
    Employee pracownik = ligiConnection.Employes.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeID == id);
    return View(pracownik);
}
```

And `global.asax.cs` code

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MVCDemo.Models.ligiConnection>(null);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me, why I am receiving an error

> Invalid object name 'dbo.tabelka'

on this line:

```
Employee pracownik = ligiConnection.Employes.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeID == id);
```

Comment: What database are you connecting to? Does it contain a table called `dbo.tabelka` ??

Comment: I'am using Sql Server. Yes, database contain a table with that name. In "web forms" I'am using sql connection to receive data from this table and everything works fine..

Comment: Exceptions don't lie. Are you sure your connection string is pointing to the correct database?

Comment: Yes, i am for a 100% sure of that, I checked that 10 times. The same connection string and the same table works fine with web forms and SqlCommand + SqlConnection + SqlDataReader :/

Comment: What have you checked? Did you check `ligiConnection.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`?

Comment: Honestly, I dont know what You mean. I dont uderstand why there sholud be any problem with connection string which one works fine on a different web application.

Comment: Can You xplain me how can I check that "ligiConnection.Database.Connection.ConnectionString" ?, what You mean with that ?. I have to resolved this problem, because I cannot do anything more :/